# How to add floating label on Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, material-design, android-textinputlayout

After using the Android Design Support Library's [`TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) to place a floating label above an [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) component, I was wondering if there is a way to add a floating label to the [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) component (not necessarily using the Design Library).

By this, I mean something like a [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) placed above the `Spinner` (obviously no animations like the `TextInputLayout`), but I want the **text size, font and colour to match that of the `TextInputLayout`'s floating label**.

For example, it would look something like this (see the labels above the `Spinner`s):

[image]

As I mentioned before, my main aim is to have a label above the `Spinner`, just as in the `TextInputLayout` - so text size, font, colour, and distances between the label and the component would be the same.

On the [Google Design page about floating label text fields](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels), there is a diagram showing dimensions of the label relative to the component, but there is no indication of the label text colour or size:

[image]

**So, to summarise, I am asking:**
- If there is a special component to achieve what I am asking or a custom view I can use, what would it be, and how can I use it.
- If not, what is the floating label text size, colour and font, so that I can place a `TextView` above my `Spinner` with the layout dimensions shown in the above image.

---

## **EDIT:**

From the [Google Design guidelines for text fields](https://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels), it has the following for floating labels:

> Hint and input font: Roboto Regular 16sp
>   Label font: Roboto Regular 12sp
>   Tile height: 72dp
>   Text top and bottom padding: 16dp
>   Text field divider padding: 8dp

as well as the images shown above.

So the floating label font is: ***Roboto Regular 12sp***. You can therefore use a `TextView` to display the `Spinner` label as I do not know of any custom `View`s or special components you could use.

**However**, after trying it out, it does not look quite as good as the example shown in the image. A **custom view may be better for this**, as it could look nicer, but the solution above is just one way of achieving something close to what I originally wanted.

Answer (score 45):

> I want the **text size, font and colour to match that of the `TextInputLayout`'s floating label**.

This can be achieved easily without any external libraries. After trying to hack the `TextInputLayout` and even making my own custom view, I realized that using a simple `TextView` takes much less code and it's probably more efficient.

The text style **can be copied** from the `AppCompat` library.

## The style

From the Material Design guidelines we get the following information:

- the label should have a bottom margin of `8dp`
- the label should be vertically aligned with the input text

Here's what the guidelines do not mention about the Material `EditText`:

- it has a left padding of `4dp`
- its label actually doesn't have any spacing of `16dp` above it, this is left to the interface designer: this makes sense because if you place it under another `EditText`, you will only need an additional `8dp` of space

Moreover, the Design Support Library contains this style for the label of a focused element:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Design.Hint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
</style>
```

Inactive elements simply use `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption`.

## Implementation

Add the following to your `dimens.xml` file:

```
<dimen name="input_label_vertical_spacing">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="input_label_horizontal_spacing">4dp</dimen>
```

Then add this to `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="InputLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/input_label_vertical_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/input_label_horizontal_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/input_label_horizontal_spacing</item>
</style>
```

If you want the label to always have the highlighted (accent) color, replace `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption` with `TextAppearance.Design.Hint` from the Google Design Support Library. However, this will probably look a bit weird if you also have labeled `EditText` views on the same screen.

Finally, you can put a `TextView` above your `Spinner` (or any other element) with the style applied:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/category"
    style="@style/InputLabel" />
```

## Result

The following screenshot shows a simple example with two normal `TextInputLayout` views followed by a label and a `Spinner`. I didn't apply the additional `8dp` spacing to separate them further, but this shows you that the size, font and color are reflected.

The elements inside the `Spinner` have a different padding, however I prefer to keep the vertical alignment with all the other labels to get a more uniform look.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly possible to achieve this without external libraries. In fact, I used the same approach when creating my custom view, which is actually a compound view consisting of the styled TextView, Spinner and divider View. The reason I made the custom view was because it is easier to manage as one view in the layout hierarchy, instead of trying to manage two or three views.

Comment: You probably want to add `<item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorHint</item>` in your style to get the same text color in the custom label as used in TextInputLayout in unfocused state.

Comment: *"However, this will probably look a bit weird if you also have labeled EditText views on the same screen."*... 
**You can just be specific and name the style `SpinnerLabel` instead of `InputLabel` so that you only use them for spinners.**

Comment: _"The elements inside the Spinner have a different padding, however I prefer to keep the vertical alignment with all the other labels to get a more uniform look."_

If you'd nevertheless like to apply that same left padding to the label so that it aligns with the spinner elements, the value is **8dp**, as defined [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml;l=397).

Answer (score 36):

I achieved this by using an AutoCompleteTextView, disabling the keyboard and showing the options on touch.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations));

AutoCompleteTextView mTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.location);

mTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
mTextView.setKeyListener(null);
mTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        ((AutoCompleteTextView) v).showDropDown();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution.  This is a small hack, and allows to use the standard `TextInputLayout`, thus ensuring you will have the exact correct appearance.

Comment: Just a small improvement: use `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

Comment: Very clever hack. But it is still a hack though.

Comment: If you use `mTextView.setText(...)`, you will not receive all values from adapter in drop down... Calling `adapter.getFilter().filter(null);` shows again all suggestions

Comment: also if you set text, you then cannot close the dropdown programmatically

Comment: If you call `setKeyListener(null)` then physical keyboards will not be able to trigger the autocomplete, so this solution is incomplete as written.

Comment: Sadly this breaks most UI testing tools as AutoCompleteTextView does an odd pop-up that can't be seen as part of the screen.

Comment: for showing all suggestion `if (!mTextView.getText().toString().equals("")) adapter.getFilter().filter(null)` should be called inside the onTouch Listener before showDropDown
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40482975/5194344

Answer (score 34):

I have a gist made by myself to solve the same problem that you have.

Check It out:

https://gist.github.com/rodrigohenriques/77398a81b5d01ac71c3b

Now I don't need spinners. You will still having floating label effect with animations included.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"I don't need spinners"_, and where in your gist, you say _"Used to make your EditText a better option than Spinners"_? Is the UI simply an EditText?

Comment: I use EditText with TextInput Layout as an alternative for spinners. When the user click in this custom EditText I open a dialog with options to select. Of course It could be better and I accept any improvement like to show the options with another kinds of views just like spinner.

Comment: Could you make it clearer on how to implement the View (usage). There are various parts of the code that seem to be missing, and so I'm not sure how to fill in the gaps.

Comment: I will upgrade this gist into a github project with samples then I hope to get help to improve this solution.

Comment: Add `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` to the `onDraw(canvas)` method to disable any input into the edittext. Otherwise e.g. long clicks will bring up a context menu and enable the user to paste text.

Comment: Thanks @Capricorn. I will fix this.

Comment: well this was awesome, but if you ever decided to upgrade it into a github library, make sure to give an option to choose between `EditText` or `AppCompatEditText`, please !

Comment: label is not floating

Answer (score 11):

I have created a compound `View` component which displays a label above the `Spinner`. The text for the label can be set using XML or in Java.

The component has the key features of a `Spinner` (*not all* of them) as well as looking similar to the `TextInputLayout` component.

I have named it a [`LabelledSpinner`](https://github.com/farbodsz/UsefulViews/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/satsuware/usefulviews/LabelledSpinner.java), and it is available as part of my [**UsefulViews**](https://github.com/farbodsz/UsefulViews) Android library on GitHub under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

To use it, add the library dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:+'
```

Examples of its usage are available at the GitHub repository (both a sample app, and a usage guide).

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal Let me know what exactly doesn't work or open an issue on the repo

Comment: Actually its working , but label is not float like edittext

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal There is a small label positioned above the `Spinner`, which is similar to how there are small labels above `EditText` components, wrapped in `TextInputLayout`. How did you imagine it to be?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh This is a cool library to use, but it doesn't work on Lollipop.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh Yep, InflateException on API 23

Comment: not working on gradle 3.5, only gradle 2.0 very old library

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this :
[image]

With new Material library styles like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullNameLay"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/fullNameEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

for more information:
https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/

**UPDATE:**
Non editable variation:
Disable the user input in the *`*AutoCompleteTextView*`* to have a non editable variation of the menu by setting `android:inputType="none"` on the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: it's not spinner

Comment: it is a spinner, only with a different design

Answer (score 5):

I modified Rodrigo's solution to use an adapter, i.e. more like a standard Spinner
https://gist.github.com/smithaaron/d2acd57937d7a4201a79

Answer (score 5):

I have an alternative solution that uses the behavior of TextInputLayout and a custom DialogFragment (AlertDialog) to emulate a spinner dialog popup.

layout.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/your_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/your_label"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:focusable="false"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Create Custom Spinner via DialogFragment (AlertDialog)

SpinnerFragment.java:

```
public class SpinnerFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TITLEID = "titleId";
private static final String LISTID = "listId";
private static final String EDITTEXTID = "editTextId";

public static SpinnerFragment newInstance(int titleId, int listId, int editTextId) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(TITLEID, titleId);
    bundle.putInt(LISTID, listId);
    bundle.putInt(EDITTEXTID, editTextId);
    SpinnerFragment spinnerFragment = new SpinnerFragment();
    spinnerFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return spinnerFragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final int titleId = getArguments().getInt(TITLEID);
    final int listId = getArguments().getInt(LISTID);
    final int editTextId = getArguments().getInt(EDITTEXTID);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    try {
        final String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(listId);

        builder.setTitle(titleId)
                .setItems(listId, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                        EditText et = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(editTextId);
                        String selectedText = items[pos];
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                            et.setText(selectedText);
                        } else {
                            et.getText().clear();
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().toString(), "Failed to select option in " + getActivity().toString() + " as there are no references for passed in resource Ids in Bundle", e);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_failed_to_select), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Activity.java:

```
private void addCustomSpinner() {
    EditText yourEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_et);
    yourEt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showCustomSpinnerDialog(view);
        }
    });
}

private void showCustomSpinnerDialog(View v) {
    int titleId = R.string.your_label;
    int listId = R.array.spinner_selections;
    int editTextId = R.id.your_et;
    SpinnerFragment spinnerFragment = SpinnerFragment.newInstance(titleId, listId, editTextId);
    spinnerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "customSpinner");
}
```

**Result**

When you click on the spinner styled TextInputLayout, it will trigger an alert dialog containing your list of selections. Once a selection is chosen, the EditText will be populated with your selection and the label will float like how you want.

Comment: Doesn't `android:focusable="false"` make this view inaccessible to those using keyboard or voice to interact with the app?

Comment: I have never used keyboard or voice to interact with a spinner, but the reason why I set `android:focusable="false"` is so the user cannot type an input that is not amongst the selection. Unfortunately, I don't have a physical Android phone to test out the behaviors to let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my trick,

the good things is that everything will work like you want,

but the bad is that it is increasing layout hierarchy, and you have to handle functionality in code, and it is an ugly solution:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/edt_height"
                android:hint="@string/create_gcc_visa_txt_step" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spn"
            style="@style/MyAppTheme.Base.Spinner"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edt_height"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/til" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and override adapter for spinner, to make selected values transparent

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    Context mContext;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.transparent));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and after selecting in spinner, just get selected text and set it to EditText and it will have the same effect with animation

```
yourSpinnerView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<String> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //get your selected text from adapter or from where you want 
            String selectedText = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

            if (i != 0) { 
                edt.setText(selectedText);
            } else { 
                // if in case your spinner have first empty text, 
                // then when spinner selected, just empty EditText.
                edt.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

if you have any question Ask me

Comment: can you help me i m getting stuck? i have multiple edit text so oncreate of layout focus goes to first edittext and while directly i am pressing spinner so above code of edittext not get focus .but i need to get focus on click of spinner how can i?

Comment: @sunita can you please tell my the order of the view, because when i am trying i was able to focus on spinner

Answer (score 1):

Here is a library that I use for the Floating label spinner
[rey5137 Material Library](https://github.com/rey5137/material)

Also, for future reference, here is a list of some great libraries.
[UI Libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui)
[Core Libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

SpinnerCustom.java

```
package com.pozitron.tfkb.customviews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.pozitron.commons.customviews.TextViewFont;
import com.pozitron.tfkb.R;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by so12607 on 31/01/2018.
 */

public class SpinnerCustom extends LinearLayout {

    @BindView(R.id.layoutSpinnerCustomLabel)
    TextViewFont layoutSpinnerCustomLabel;

    @BindView(R.id.layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner)
    TextViewFont layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner;

    @BindView(R.id.layoutSpinner)
    LinearLayout layoutSpinner;

    private View v;

    public SpinnerCustom(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SpinnerCustom(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }

    public SpinnerCustom(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_spinner_custom, this, true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {

            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SpinnerCustom, 0, 0);
            final String label = array.getString(R.styleable.SpinnerCustom_label);
            final boolean enable = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.SpinnerCustom_enabled, true);
            layoutSpinnerCustomLabel.setText(label);

            layoutSpinnerCustomLabel.setEnabled(enable);
            layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner.setEnabled(enable);
            layoutSpinner.setEnabled(enable);
            layoutSpinner.setClickable(enable);
            v.setEnabled(enable);
            v.setClickable(enable);
            array.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner.setText(text);
    }

    public void setText(SpannableString text) {
        layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner.setText(text);
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text) {
        layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner.setText(text);
    }

    public void setLabel(String text) {
        layoutSpinnerCustomLabel.setText(text);
    }

    public void setError(SpannableString text) {
        layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner.setError(text);
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enable) {
        layoutSpinnerCustomLabel.setEnabled(enable);
        layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner.setEnabled(enable);
        layoutSpinner.setEnabled(!enable);
        layoutSpinner.setClickable(!enable);
    }
}
```

layout_spinner_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.pozitron.commons.customviews.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/layoutSpinnerCustomLabel"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        tools:text="label" />

    <com.pozitron.commons.customviews.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/layoutSpinnerCustomSpinner"
        style="@style/SpinnerText"
        android:clickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="font">@integer/font_GTEestiDisplay_Regular</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/greyLabel</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerText" parent="EditText">
    <item name="font">@integer/font_GTEestiDisplay_Medium</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/select</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_spinner_text</item>
</style>
```