# how to implement spinner with floating label?

Tags: android-layout, material-design, android-spinner, floating

I tried using AutoCompleteTextView to do this.

```
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_64sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:elevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorDarkGreyOne">

                            <AutoCompleteTextView
                                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTvCountry"
                                style="@style/StyleEditText"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                                android:hint="@string/label_country"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                                android:textSize="17.3sp"/>

                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>




 and using array adapter:

  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryNameList);
    AutoCompleteTextView mTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTvCountry);
    mTextView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    mTextView.setKeyListener(null);
    mTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            ((AutoCompleteTextView) v).showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I am facing two problems:
  1. unable to get the @Override method  onItemSelected  which is required and 
  2. In the dropdown list of country, countries are too close like below image

[image]

how to solve this problem or any other way to do spinner with floating lebel having @Override method  onItemSelected?

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625620/how-to-add-floating-label-on-spinner

Comment: I took the AutoCompleteTextView solution from your given link. @ noureldien